pip install fails confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error
Good day guys.
I'm building a little Python Docker image for beginner study purposes using Ubuntu in Windows through WSL. In my home/ directory I have a flask-app/ directory with the following files:
Dockerfile
# our base image
FROM alpine:latest

# Install python and pip
RUN apk add --update py2-pip

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# install Python modules needed by the Python app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy files required for the app to run
COPY app.py /usr/src/app/
COPY templates/index.html /usr/src/app/templates/

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the application
CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/app.py"]

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

# list of cat images
images = [
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26388-1381844103-11.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr01/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-31540-1381844535-8.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26390-1381844163-18.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-1376-1381846217-0.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-3391-1381844336-26.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-29111-1381845968-0.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-3409-1381844582-13.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr02/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-19667-1381844937-10.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26358-1381845043-13.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-18774-1381844645-6.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-25158-1381844793-0.gif",
    "http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-11980-1381846269-1.gif"
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = random.choice(images)
    return render_template('index.html', url=url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")


requirements.txt
Flask==1.0

templates/index.html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background: black;
        color: white;
      }
      div.container {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        border: 20px solid white;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      h4 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h4>Cat Gif of the day</h4>
      <img src="{{url}}" />
      <p><small>Courtesy: <a href="http://www.buzzfeed.com/copyranter/the-best-cat-gif-post-in-the-history-of-cat-gifs">Buzzfeed</a></small></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

When I try to build my Docker image with docker build -t <MY_USERNAME>/myfirstapp . I get the following error:
alain@testlab:~/flask-app$ docker build -t <MY_USERNAME>/myfirstapp .
[+] Building 3.5s (9/11)                                                                                                                                                                          docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 566B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.5                                                                                                                                               0.8s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.5@sha256:66952b313e51c3bd1987d7c4ddf5dba9bc0fb6e524eed2448fa660246b3e76ec                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.46kB                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apk add --update py2-pip                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [3/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                                                     1.3s
 => [4/7] COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/                                                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => ERROR [5/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt                                                                                                                             1.2s
------
 > [5/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt:
0.874 Collecting Flask==1.0 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
0.949   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726) - skipping
0.950   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
0.951 No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0 (from -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     # install Python modules needed by the Python app
  11 |     COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
  12 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
  13 |
  14 |     # copy files required for the app to run
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I've tried this solution with the --trusted-host flag, and this other solution, but so far I have the same problem.
Since there are some TSL versions that has been deprecated by Python, I have made sure to upgrade pip to the latest version with curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.
This is my current pip version:
alain@testlab:~/flask-app$ pip --version
pip 24.2 from /home/alain/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

This is my current Python and its OpenSSL version:
alain@testlab:~/flask-app$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

What could be happening?
Huge thanks in advance!

Any specific reasons you use alpine:3.5 instead of latest versions?

No @alko, no particular reason. I've change it to latest and the end result it's the same. But thanks for the observation.

The official python on Dockerhub includes versions using alpine; this will save you some steps.
Perhaps:
Ensure that you're using the latest version of Flask
requirements.txt:
Flask==3.0.3

Dockerfile:
# our base image
FROM docker.io/python:3.12.5-alpine3.19

# Using WORKDIR is more idiomatic and saves repeated use of the folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install Python modules needed by the Python app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt

# copy files required for the app to run
COPY app.py .
COPY templates/index.html ./templates/

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

Q=78871861

docker build \
--tag=stackoverflow:${Q} \
--file=${PWD}/Dockerfile \
${PWD}

docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=5000:5000/tcp \
stackoverflow:${Q}

 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://10.0.2.100:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
10.0.2.100 - - [14/Aug/2024 16:13:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.0.2.100 - - [14/Aug/2024 16:13:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.0.2.100 - - [14/Aug/2024 16:13:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.0.2.100 - - [14/Aug/2024 16:13:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

And then browse http://localhost:5000

Thank you for your answer @DazWilkin. This is the output I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/src/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)

Actually, one (important) change (that I forgot to include) is that you should use the latest version of Flask.... Flask==3.0.3 in your requirements.txt. I'll update the answer.

Yes, I confirmed that if you use the old version of Flask=-1.0, you will get the errors you show. Please ensure you're using Flask==3.0.3

Working like a charm @DazWilkin. Thank you very much sir!

You're welcome. Sorry about the oversight of Flask==3.0.3.
